# Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Tags: php, mysql

Hi can someone explain why I'm receiving this error?
**Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in**

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM load_test                                                            WHERE batch_id=UCASE('".$batchid."') 
AND word='".$data[2]."',
type='".$data[3]."',
language = '".$data[4]."',
rgender = '".$data[5]."'
"), 0) == 0) {
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938959/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-reso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey! You're missing `AND` between conditions! Don't use commas!

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM load_test
          WHERE batch_id=UCASE('".$batchid."')
          AND word='".$data[2]."'
          AND type='".$data[3]."'
          AND language = '".$data[4]."'
          AND rgender = '".$data[5]."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

In this way you'll can catch the mysql error you are getting when you execute the query.

Comment: i added in the AND's and still same error. I need to check if the item is present in the table or not.

Comment: try to implement the code above I wrote. It will show you the exact error. Don't just pass one function to another.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem was the commas i had at the end.